# Arithmetic mean and Geometric mean Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

The arithmetic mean of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is $A(a,b) = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and the geometric mean of of $a,b \in [0,\infty)$ is $G(a,b) = \sqrt{ab}$. If $0 \lt a \lt b$

Prove that $a \leq G(a,b) \leq A(a,b) \leq b$ Also prove that $G(a,b) = A(a,b)$ if and only if $a = b$.

We did not cover anything like this in class the only thing we covered were field axioms, triangle inequality, and proofs by cases. I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: First write down what you want to prove (e.g., the first inequality you are asked to prove is $a \le \sqrt{ab}$) and stare at it. Check what assumptions you have (e.g., $0 < a < b$). Can you rearrange things to show that the desired inequality is true?

Comment: To get started, observe that $\sqrt{}$ is monotonically increasing on the positive reals, hence $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$. Multiply both sides by the positive number $\sqrt{a}$ to conclude that $a = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$. Similarly, $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2} < \frac{b}{2} + \frac{b}{2} = b$. So $G(a,b) \leq A(a,b)$ is the only interesting part.

Comment: @Bungo what is montonically increasing mean? So i can assume that $\sqrt{a} \lt \sqrt{ab}$ But what if a and b are less than 1 then the opposite would be true ?

Comment: Nobody said $\sqrt a<\sqrt{ab}.$ You’re forgetting one of the $\sqrt a$ factors.

Comment: I guess my question is how can i deduce that $\sqrt{a} \lt \sqrt{b}$?

Comment: I am going to have to justify in my statement that it is monotonically increasing so now I have $a \lt \sqrt{ab} \lt \frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: squaring both sides gives $ab \lt \frac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to
$$a^2\le ab\le \frac{a^2+b^2+2ab}{4}\le b^2$$

Comment: How am I supposed to deduce that?

Comment: It is $$a^2\le ab$$ equivalent to $$a\le b$$

Comment: @K.Gibson You we’re supposed to show that $0<a\leq G(a,b)\leq A(a,b)\leq b.$ Since all the numbers are positive, they must be in the same numerical order as their squares. Try squaring everything; what happens?

Comment: And $$ab\le \frac{ a^2+b^2+2ab}{4}$$ equivalent to $$(a-b)^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that $AM \geq GM$, one may proceed as it follows
\begin{align*}
(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^{2} \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow a - 2\sqrt{ab} + b \geq0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}
\end{align*}

In order to prove that $AM \leq b$, just take the difference:
\begin{align*}
b - \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{2b - (a+b)}{2} = \frac{b-a}{2} > 0
\end{align*}

Finally, to prove that $a \leq GM$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a} \leq \sqrt{b} \Longleftrightarrow a \leq \sqrt{ab}
\end{align*}

Hope this helps.

Comment: You meant to write $\frac{b - a}{2} \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $a=1$ because you can divide $a$ anb $b$ by $a$.

Then, squaring

$$1\le\sqrt{b}\le\frac{1+b}2\le b,$$

we obtain $$1\le b\le\frac{1+2b+b^2}4\le b^2,$$

then

$$1-b\le 0\le\frac{1-2b+b^2}4\le b^2-b.$$

The middle equality holds iff $1=b$. Otherwise, dividing by $b-1$,

$$-1\le 0\le\frac{b-1}4\le b.$$